# Can't get the element height for positioning an element to center by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, positioning

I am trying to center a span inside a paragraph using JavaScript. This is my code :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>  {
    window.onload = function(){middle();}
    var titleHeight = document.getElementById("page-title").clientHeight;
    var titleWidth = document.getElementById("page-title").clientWidth;
    var objHeight = document.getElementById("head-text").clientHeight;
    var objWidth = document.getElementById("head-text").clientHeight;
    var moveit = document.getElementById("head-text");
    var moveit = document.getElementById("head-text");
    function middle(){
        console.log(titleHeight/2-objHeight/2);
        moveit.style.top=titleHeight/2-objHeight/2;
        moveit.style.left=titleWidth/2-objWidth/2);
        }
})
```

It always returns undefined for the **titleHeight**.How do I solve this?

I tried centering the element by css but that doesn't help.So I had to switch to JavaScript. I need any possible was by JavaScript to position my element.

Comment: FYI: There is rather little point in nesting a `load` into a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler.

Comment: We need a proper [mre] from you when you ask this kind of question, not just a snippet that lacks context.

Comment: Why do you need JavaScript for this? This is what CSS was built for....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should do this with CSS, but in JS you need to call `element.getBoundingClientRect()` to get accurate positional information.

Also, you're setting `objWidth` to `clientHeight`.

It's quite slow and will cause jank, but...

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>  {
    window.onload = function(){middle();}


    function middle(){
        // This can change, so needs to be in the `middle` function
        const title = document.getElementById("page-title").getBoundingClientRect();
        const titleHeight = title.height;
        const titleWidth = title.width;

        const moveit = document.getElementById("head-text");
        const head = moveit.getBoundingClientRect();
        const objHeight = title.height;
        const objWidth = title.width; // fix typo

        console.log(titleHeight/2-objHeight/2);

        moveit.style.top=(titleHeight/2-objHeight/2)+"px";
        moveit.style.left=(titleWidth/2-objWidth/2)+"px";
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Might bee problematic because span is default inline html. Try to set  css and define it as inline-block, before the javascript manipulation:

```
span: { display: inline-block}
```